# How can I remove a directory that I own when it contains subdirectories owned by another user?

Tags: debian, unix, permissions, rm

I have created a directory `/home/web/test` on a Debian server using a basic unprivileged account `web`. Another account — `tomcat` — then created some subdirectories and files in that folder (as you might have guessed, `tomcat` is a web application).

I would like to delete that test folder now, but I can't be because `tomcat` owns directories and files under it. I get *Permission Denied* errors when I try. Here's how it's set up:

ls -l /home/web

```
drwxrwxrwx 3 web users 4096 2011-04-19 12:06 test
```

ls -l /home/web/test

```
drwxr-xr-x 46 tomcat tomcat 4096 2011-04-19 12:06 www
```

ls -l /home/web/test/www

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat tomcat  9939 2011-04-19 12:44 test1.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat tomcat 16346 2011-04-19 12:44 test2.html
...
```

rm -rf /home/web/test

```
rm: cannot remove `/home/web/test/www/test1.html': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/web/test/www/test2.html': Permission denied
...
```

Is there any way that I can delete the `/home/web/test` folder using the `web` account — ie without logging in as `tomcat` or `root`?

After all, I own `/home/web/test`, shouldn't I be able to do anything I want with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, as far as I can tell. You gave the tomcat user your permission to store their files on your directory, but their files are theirs. You can't modify or delete the files if you're not their owner or a member of their group (and you're not using extended ACLs).

Their location on the filesystem is pretty much irrelevant anyway as the same inode can be referenced multiple times on multiple locations. It's just not the way Unix permissions work - they are inode-based, not location-based.

EDIT: That's an interesting observation @syserr0r. The reason for this is that you, as the owner of a directory, can make changes to its file list - including deleting a file from that list (If the file has no hard links left then the operating system deletes the inode). So my answer is not correct: for creation and deletion the permissions that matter are the ones of the parent directory, not the ones associated to the inode.

Comment: +1 for mentioning inode... reading up on inodes explained a lot to me. I'm used to NTFS where ACLs inherit nicely down the directory tree, the inode approach is very different.

Answer (score 2):

#### Single Folder

`~/test` with `drwxr-xr-x` owned by `gompels` group `gompels`
`~/test/test0r` with `-rw-r--r--` owned by `root` group `root`

`gompels@stonewall:~$rm -Rf test` and the <strike>dirt</strike> folder is gone!

#### Nested Folder

`~/test` with `drwxr-xr-x` owned by `gompels` group `gompels`
`~/test/test2/` with `drwxr-xr-x` owned by `root` group `root`
`~/test/test2/test0r` with `-rw-r--r--` owned by `root` group `root`

`gompels@stonewall:~$rm -Rf test` and `rm: cannot remove 'test/test2/test0r': Permission denied`  fail :(

So if you own the folder you can delete other peoples files in it, but not their folders.

Comment: Interesting... and I was surprised that it isn't all-or-nothing: I would have expected that either you can *always* delete the folder or you *never* can delete it; that you *might* be able to was unexpected. But after reading about inodes I think it makes more sense why it behaves so unnaturally.